# How do i stop redirection on clicking Login button when user-name & password empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Javascript Jquery Experts,

I need a little help here.

This is my code, when i click on login button without putting any value in user-name & password it show message "All fields are required" but instantly as showen this message it dissapear and display unexpected message like you see when click on login button.

Now what i want ? i want when it display "All fields are required" then this message should be stable not redirect to the other unexpected message.

check also in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m1aaaqo9/14/

1: when you click on login button checking in jsfiddle it redirect to this message: **{"error":"key missing: title"}**

2: I also put the same coding in my page: https://testjsvascripts.blogspot.com/p/javascript-test.html

Now when you click on login on my given page, it will redirect to display this message **"Method not allowed error 405**" and also add # after .html in url which i dont want.

3: same when you click on run snippet here and click on login without putting any value in user-name & password fields it will show this message **"The custom error module does not recognize this error."**

So my question is that: i want to display only this message " All fields are required " thats is..there should be no further redirections....So how to fix it in my code. ?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                var name= $("#name").val();
                var pass = $("#pass").val();
                if(name == '' || pass == ''){
                    $("#Required").html("All Fields Are Required").css("color","red");
                }else if(name == "admin" && pass == "123"){
                     $("#form").html('<h4>User Login Successfully</h4><a href="">Back</a>').css('color','green');
                }else{
                     $("#error").html("User Are Not Valid");
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Validation Form</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <span>Name:admin</span>
    <span>password:123</span>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form action="#" method="post" class="form-box" id="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="pass" class="btn btn-md btn-info" value="Login"/>
                    <span id="Required" style="color:#ff0000;"></span>
                </div>
                <span id="error" style="color:#ff0000"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you change the type of the button to `type='button'` what is happening than?

Comment: just change the type of the submit button to only `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: @NaveedAli Thank you man! your idea worked...I have one another question can you just add on statement in the javascript if user put wrong password it should display a message " You enter Wrong Password" now when i put wrong user name instead of admin it appear message "user not valid" same i want for password field separetly, when put wrong password it should display message " you enter wrong password" thanks

Comment: if this helped you then kindly accept the answer so that it helped other people in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                var name= $("#name").val();
                var pass = $("#pass").val();
                if(name == '' || pass == ''){
                    $("#Required").html("All Fields Are Required").css("color","red");
                }else if(name == "admin" && pass == "123"){
                     $("#form").html('<h4>User Login Successfully</h4><a href="">Back</a>').css('color','green');
                }else{
                     $("#error").html("User Are Not Valid");
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
```

```html
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Validation Form</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <span>Name:admin</span>
    <span>password:123</span>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form action="#" method="post" class="form-box" id="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="pass" class="btn btn-md btn-info" value="Login"/>
                    <span id="Required" style="color:#ff0000;"></span>
                </div>
                <span id="error" style="color:#ff0000"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: return false from the click function

Comment: now it has another problem here buddy ? when i put user name wrong instead of admin it does not give me the message "user is not valid" So your script is not showing when putting wrong user name instead of admin....Now do one thing if user field has another value instead of admin it should give this message "user is not valid" thanks

Comment: Thanks bundles man your code is more valuable than Naveed shared, Your code is also working fine on my wordpress page..could you tell me which changes you made ? thanks

Comment: i found you write statement  "return false;" in script....You also changed any html tag ? thanks

Comment: I didn't change the html tag, just added a return false inside the click function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                var name= $("#name").val();
                var pass = $("#pass").val();
                if(name == '' || pass == ''){
                    $("#Required").html("All Fields Are Required").css("color","red");
                }else if(name == "admin" && pass == "123"){
                     $("#form").html('<h4>User Login Successfully</h4><a href="">Back</a>').css('color','green');
                }else{
                     $("#error").html("User Are Not Valid");
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Validation Form</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <span>Name:admin</span>
    <span>password:123</span>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form action="#" method="post" class="form-box" id="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="button" id="submit" name="pass" class="btn btn-md btn-info" value="Login"/>
                    <span id="Required" style="color:#ff0000;"></span>
                </div>
                <span id="error" style="color:#ff0000"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not yet though, although if this helped you then marking it as answered would be helpful for others in future.

Comment: if you will help people, then people will help you. :)